# My WordPress site must be being affected by outside sources

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting, canonical-url, error, malware

Some of my pages are resulting in 310 errors (too many redirects). We recently switched domains from kgstiles.com to healthmasterysystems.com then discovered healthmasterysystems.com was listed as not trust-worthy by Google and really strange popups kept coming up. Google had had a malicious site warning dating back to March - long before we got it, so yesterday we switched it back.

If you go to http://www.kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/, it redirects to kgstiles.com/missing/. I have installed all sorts of plugins to stop it, I have changed the permalink structure, cleared `.htaccess`, repaired the database, etc. Nothing ever worked.

So I restored the database and all of the files to before we switched domains and the problem still persists! Is it safe to assume something outside of the website is affecting it? What could possibly be happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to assume something outside of the website is affecting it?

No.  Your WordPress installation may have malware injected into it and the steps you listed above are not sufficient to clean a hacked WordPress install.  If one of the core files has been modified to attempt to redirect visitors to an attack site you may see 310 errors or all sorts of other weirdness depending on exactly what has been modified.

Even if WordPress is clean, your server may be compromised by an attacker and you are seeing the effect of requests being redirected or otherwise modified.  This is less likely than a WordPress hack so I would look to assess that first.  Re-enable your site and do a quick scan at [Sucuri.net](http://sucuri.net) and see if anything jumps up via their basic scan.  If not, you are going to have go through all post content in the database and look for injected code and do the same for plugins.  There are some plugins that will [make](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tac/) [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-check/) [easier](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gotmls/).

Sorry that this is happening to you and it can be difficult and frustrating to pinpoint the problem.  Keep working at it and you should get to the bottom of it.